# Why does my app blocking response to client with KernelEvents::TERMINATE

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony and one feature is to upload some files to Google Drive.
This behavior is triggered when an external API (which I don't have control on) sends a request on a specific route.

The problem is that the upload of the files to the Drive takes some times, and the remote API justs timeout waiting for a response.

I went online to do some search and found that I can use Listeners : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#connecting-listeners

The problem is with all that setup, the response is still taking the same time.

Service ctor :

```
private $eventDispatcher;

public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher) {
     $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
}
```

Here is the code in my Service, `uploadFileToDriveMultiple(...)` function :

```
$this->eventDispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function (Event $event) use ($prmParentFolderIdArray, $prmFilesNamesArray, $prmFilesPathsArray) {
    // Upload here
});
```

And in the Controller :

```
$serviceDrive->uploadFileToDriveMultiple($filesParent, $filesName, $filesPath);
```

Did I miss setting up something ?
Any help is appreciated

Thank you !

Comment: Did I miss it in your question or were you just pasting the code that did not solve your problem and it now appears as if you would ask about that code instead about the code you actually have the problem with?

Comment: Hello, sorry if my question is unclear.
I don't undersand why the code in the ``uploadFileToDriveMultiple``function, in the eventListener is blocking the response to the client.
I have to wait the files upload in order to get a response from the server even if I made it to trigger on ``TERMINATE`` event.

Comment: That is because it does not already run. You have the code but as this is a file-upload, the code will not run *until* the file has already been uploaded. Symfony is still PHP, check with the basics first and do the tweaking later. Otherwise you may just tweak and change but all in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed `php-fpm` which will use `fastcgi_finish_request` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

After modifying my DockerFile and rebuilding an image, it works perfectly.

The code works with `php` aswell, but you'll get no benefits from it, so if you're trying to achieve the same thing, be sure to use `php-fpm`